# QGIS enmap-box plugin error

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, numpy, runtimeerror, enmap-box

I just now downloaded a plugin named "EnMAP Box". I am a user of QGIS v.3.28.12. It shows me the following error: An error has occured while executing Python code:

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf . Check the section C-API incompatibility at the Troubleshooting ImportError section at https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html#c-api-incompatibility for indications on how to solve this problem .
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf . Check the section C-API incompatibility at the Troubleshooting ImportError section at https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html#c-api-incompatibility for indications on how to solve this problem .

Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
QGIS version: 3.28.12-Firenze Firenze, dcc633b2de

Lokalizacja Pythona:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.12/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/natalie/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/natalie/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.12/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.12\apps\grass\grass83\etc\python
C:\Users\natalie\Documents
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.12\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.12\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.12\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.12\bin
C:\Users\natalie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.12\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.12\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.12\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.12\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.12\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/natalie/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\natalie\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows
C:\Users/natalie/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\site-packages
C:\Users\natalie\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\qgispluginsupport\qps\pyqtgraph
C:\Users\natalie\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\site-packages
C:\Users\natalie\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\apps
C:\Users\natalie\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\coreapps
C:\Users\natalie\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\eo4qapps
C:\Users/natalie/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\site-packages
C:\Users/natalie/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin
C:\Users\natalie\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\site-packages

Comment: Did you do anything to QGIS' python environment? Did you install numpy to it somehow manually?

Comment: A new python has been downloaded. After installation the problem started.
When trying to install numphu manually in cmd, the process failed.

Comment: You will either have to learn a lot about Python environments and then you might be able to recover this, or you best re-install QGIS and then before manually installing any packages somewhere, ask or search about the goal you want to achieve.